# chrome send post request can't get request body

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I send a post request to windows local service(c#) at http://127.0.0.1:13728.
When i open the website at chrome, my local service can't get request body.
Windows service code:

```
string recData = new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

request:

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIA40.png)

[request payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAl6V.png)

The recData is null or empty.
When i open it at ie or other browser, it works fine.
The Chrome works fine before. But recently it suddenly doesn't work.
I searched a lot , but can't figure out why.

Please help.Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I find out why.
Because chrome 98 update, when request a private network, the browser will send a preflight first. But my local service ignore the preflight request and don't return anything. The preflight request status is always pending，so the really request don't send.

check this:
[Private Network Access: introducing preflights](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/)